# Create File object Type - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

I have been working on react.js to upload multiple files, I see the output in console.log,

it shows the output like - `[File, File, File]`, if I uploaded three files

Where each File contains name, path, size, last modified, etc., for corresponding file which I uploaded.

I printed the `typeof` each file and its properties, it look like this -

[image: output]

My doubt - Is it possible to create a File type object for a file saved in public folder which contains all the details of the file[name, path, lastmodified, etc.] instead of uploading them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to create `File` object instance manually using `.File()` constructor.
Syntax:

```
new File(bits, name[, options]);
```

For more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: It is working, but the size is not correct and also path to the file is not showing, do you know how to add path parameter in File type object...